# Unable to start sshd

Tags: ssh, sshd

I'm new to Ubuntu and trying to start sshd but having a lot of problems. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling ssh by running
`sudo apt-get remove openssh-client openssh-server` and `sudo apt-get install openssh-client openssh-server`. When I run `sudo service ssh restart` I get:

```
stop: Unknown instance:
ssh start/running, process 3638
```

`sudo service sshd start` gives me `unrecognized service`.

When I run `ps -A | grep ssh` I get nothing. Running `ssh localhost` gives me a connection refused.

Comment: Why is this tagged as `sshd`? I am facing a problem with it now, but it does not appear in the question, except the title.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Try purging before install:

```
sudo apt-get purge openssh-server
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Comment: turns out I `apt remove`'d openssh-server

Answer (score 16):

Ubuntu ssh service will start with ssh, not sshd.

Try:

```
 sudo apt-get remove --purge openssh-server
 sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Then try:

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

To check its status:

```
sudo service ssh status
```

Config file can be found at `/etc/init/ssh.conf`

Detail about `remove` and `purge`:

`remove` - Does NOT remove including configuration files

`purge` -  With Purge command, the configuration files are also deleted.