# How do I copy files from Linux to Windows 10 using WinSCP?

Tags: windows-10, file-sharing

**Desired Behaviour:**

I'm setting up a Windows machine next to my Linux machine as a client needs me to use some Windows specific software.

I need to copy a bunch of folders from `Linux` to `Windows 10`.

I'm trying to use `WinSCP` to achieve this, and these are the things I think I need:

**IP Address:**

`ifconfig` on Linux machine returns `inet addr: 192.xxx.x.x`

Whilst googling 'whats my ip' on Linux machine returns `118.xxx.xx.xx`

**Q01:**  Which one do I use?

**Protocol and Port Number:**

**Q02:**  SCP and 22?

**Username and Password:**

**Q03:**  Do I just use the username and password I usually use to login to my Linux machine?

...A lot of the tutorials I've come across talk about connecting to a Linux computer as a virtual machine, or server, and therefore I'm wondering if I need something to be 'running' on the Linux machine for this to work?

So, last questions:

**Q04:**  Does something need to be running on Linux?

**Q05:**  How do I define which folders will be 'browsable' on the Linux Machine?

**What I've Tried:**

My last attempt in WinSCP used these credentials:

- Protocol:  SCP
- Port: 22
- Hostname: [the `inet addr` ip from `ifconfig`]
- Username:  [my normal Linux login username]
- Password: [my normal Linux login password]

And gave me this error:

> Network error: Connection to "192.xxx.x.x" refused.

([Help page for that error](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/message_connection_refused))

**Edit:**

The answer below is more comprehensive, but as a follow up:

I did [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-start-stop-ssh-server/) on Linux machine:

```
sudo service ssh start
```

And got this:

> ssh: unrecognised service

So, I had to do [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/265985/367134):

```
sudo apt-get purge openssh-server
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

And then start with:

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

And then I used credentials in WinSCP as stated in original post and it worked.

Comment: Linux Mint 17.3 to Windows 10: both are NOT official Ubuntu sytems so off-topic on Ask *Ubuntu*

Comment: @Rinzwind This can be applied word-to-word to Ubuntu.

Comment: @BharadwajRaju that is not a valid argument: we are an *official* support site for Ubuntu. Why would we want to support a rip-off? TS should use U&L when it is about more than 1 OS and not Ubuntu anyways.

Comment: @Rinzwind Anyway, the question is now edited.

Comment: @BharadwajRaju They are still not using Ubuntu - edited or not the OP is not on Ubuntu which remains offtopic here (there IS an edit history)

Comment: So what, flag the question? Move it to U&L?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Question 1:

The second one: `118.xxx.xx.xx` - this is your *public* IP address (although if both computers are on the same network - you may use any of them)

## Question 2:

Yes (unless you change it). `22` is the default port for `SSH` (apparently - `SCP` too, since it uses `SSH` for connections). However, many change it to something else to avoid attacks.

## Question 3:

Yes.

## Question 4:

`sshd` - the SSH daemon.

1. Install `openssh-server`.
2. Copy the existing `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to a backup.
3. Edit the (non-backup) `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`
4. For security, you may want to change `Port 22` in the above file to a higher number (`2020`, for example)
5. Save.
6. Allow the port in the firewall - `sudo ufw allow {port number}`.
7. Start `sshd` - `sudo service ssh start`

Now you can access your computer's files using `{port number you chose}`

## Question 5:

You'll need to use a `chroot` jail - see [this](https://blog.tinned-software.net/restrict-linux-user-to-scp-to-his-home-directory/).